# Can I import my question from other Stack Exchange site to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, migration

I had posted a question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ about a wordpress question.I I did't get answer for that. Because the users are less compare to Stack Overflow.

If I put my question on Stack Overflow I think I will get better answers within less time.
I think its good idea to ask the question again on Stack Overflow. So I want to import that question to Stack Overflow. Anyway to do that ? Any Ideas?

Comment: There is also a possibility that the question gets closed on [so] because it is off-topic.

Comment: Is this the question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119804/how-to-edit-theme-widget-code

Comment: Is it off topic ? Then where i can ask this question?

Comment: @Yannis Whatever be the question I need to import to stackoverflow

Comment: @VinodVT Well, if the question is off topic for Stack Overflow, you won't get any answers there either.

Comment: @Yannis Leave that question. If I ask a good question on any of the stockexchange site like wordpress questions how to import that?

Comment: @VinodVT If it was closed without answers, you can simply delete it and then re-post it on Stack Overflow. If it got any answers, then you can flag it for moderation attention and ask the moderators to move it for you.

Comment: @Yannis A moderator can move that questions?

Comment: If they agree with you that the question is on topic on the site you want it moved, sure.

Comment: @Yannis Post an answer containing the substance of your comments?

Comment: @Yannis hurry up if you plan to post answer, this one going to get closed soon.

Comment: @DuncanJones Go for it, I'm on my phone and can't really type a full answer in my tiny screen (tiny in comparison with my fat fingers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [explained by Yannis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202788/can-i-import-my-question-from-other-stack-exchange-site-to-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment645216_202788) in the comments, if you think your question is a candidate for migration you can approach this in two ways:

1. You can delete the question and post the same question on Stack Overflow. There are rules determining when you can delete your own question, which [are discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/192221).
2. If you cannot delete your question, you can flag the question for moderator attention and they *might* migrate the question for you, depending upon whether they agree it is a good candidate for the other site.